# Simulating spinning animation on a vertical tire though CSS3

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am thinking of ideas and way to implement a spinning animation to a vertical tire. It looks something this:

[image]

If the tire had a side profile then it would have been easier to show it spinning but at this angle I am not sure how to simulate a spinning motion. Maybe add a little vertical blur and fade-into the static tire image?

On the contrary I am thinking maybe this shot is not enough to simulate a spinning motion. Maybe I actually need a gif or something.

Comment: May be this link will interest you http://www.romancortes.com/blog/pure-css-coke-can/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try something like below
[Tire Animation](https://jsfiddle.net/2wdf58h6/)

```
<div class="tire"></div>


.tire{
  width:340px;
  height:700px;
  background:url(http://image.prntscr.com/image/a2aa80f21c274ecbba271d4c516d33c0.png) repeat-y;
  animation: tireanimation 1s   infinite;
  border-radius:10px;
  position:relative;
}
.tire:before{
  content:'';
  width:100%;
  height:80%;
  top:-30%;
  left:0;
  opacity:.7;
  position:absolute;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 66%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 67%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(66%, rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(67%, rgba(255,255,255,0)));
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,.8) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 66%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 67%);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,.8) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 66%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 67%);
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,.8) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 66%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 67%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255,255,255,.8) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 66%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 67%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=1 );
}
.tire:after{
  content:'';
  width:100%;
  height:80%;
  bottom:-30%;
  left:0;
  opacity:.2;
  position:absolute;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 66%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 67%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(66%, rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(67%, rgba(255,255,255,0)));
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,.8) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 66%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 67%);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,.8) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 66%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 67%);
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,.8) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 66%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 67%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255,255,255,.8) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 66%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 67%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=1 );
}

@keyframes tireanimation { 
    0%{background-position:100% 0%}
    100%{background-position:100% 100%}

}
```